# background-color in css is not working when navigating from one form to another

Tags: php, css

When I try to navigate from one form to another form, background-color in css is not working.

login_form_success.php

```
<div class="alert alert-success">Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['uname']; ?>Signed in !</div>
```

style.css

```
.alert alert-success{
    background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

Comment: a side note for those who answered here : there exists a color with name greenyellow. its valid!

Answer (score 2):

Your **css** sould be.

```
.alert.alert-success{
    background-color: green;
}
```

**or**

```
.alert.alert-success{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the `<space>` with a `.` in your css:

```
.alert.alert-success{
    background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/